# Unsolved NoClassDefFoundError in Android

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror

I have spent over a week looking into this issue, and I have tried nearly every solution to be found on SO and through google, but this is still unresolved for me.

I have an external library, gdx-audio.jar, which I have imported by placing it in my libs folder and adding it too the build path.

I am using the latest version of Eclipse Juno.

So my setup looks like this:

[image: Eclipse]

Notice the libs folder with with my jar, as well as that it shows up in Android Dependencies and Referenced libraries.  Also, everything is checked in the order and export tab of the build path window, as has been a solution for some, but not for me.

Also the error message with the exception is shown in the logcat window.  (Tried to fit everything in one screenshot).

I am a bit unsure of the correct ordering of the order and export, but I have tried numerous orderings to no avail.  I have read in other peoples post to make sure gen is before src, and I have set the jar file to be made first.

Any help anyone can offer would be appreciated.

Is there anything special I need in my manifest file? Or am I just missing something small?

EDIT: Here is the LogCat output:

```
01-23 14:37:20.917: I/dalvikvm(6699): Failed resolving Lcom/badlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/KissFFT; interface 79 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable;'
01-23 14:37:20.917: W/dalvikvm(6699): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/KissFFT;' failed
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/dalvikvm(6699): Could not find class 'com.badlogic.gdx.audio.analysis.KissFFT', referenced from method ubicomp.signalproccesor.SignalProcessorDemo.<init>
01-23 14:37:20.917: W/dalvikvm(6699): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 65 (Lcom/badlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/KissFFT;) in Lubicomp/signalproccesor/SignalProcessorDemo;
01-23 14:37:20.917: D/dalvikvm(6699): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0009
01-23 14:37:20.917: I/dalvikvm(6699): Failed resolving Lcom/badlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/KissFFT; interface 79 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/utils/Disposable;'
01-23 14:37:20.917: W/dalvikvm(6699): Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdx/audio/analysis/KissFFT;' failed
01-23 14:37:20.917: D/dalvikvm(6699): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0186 at 0x0d in Lubicomp/signalproccesor/SignalProcessorDemo;.<init>
01-23 14:37:20.917: D/AndroidRuntime(6699): Shutting down VM
01-23 14:37:20.917: W/dalvikvm(6699): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40efd300)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.badlogic.gdx.audio.analysis.KissFFT
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at ubicomp.signalproccesor.SignalProcessorDemo.<init>(SignalProcessorDemo.java:41)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-23 14:37:20.917: E/AndroidRuntime(6699):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
```

Comment: Try decompiling the APK and check if you see the files, if they are not there you may need to inject the files into the project. Another way to handle this is to learn Ant or some other build compiling language and compile your project with ant using the Android SDK tools (this will definitely fix your problem).

Comment: Have you also copied the `libgdx-audio.so` files to `libs/armeabi/` and `libs/armeabi-v7a/` as mentioned [here](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2269)? Those files contain native code that gets loaded at run time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I am starting to try out both of these suggestions.  I downloaded apktool and decompiled the apk, but where exactly would I see these files if they are there? @acj I am giving your suggestion a shot next, that may be all I need.  The thing is I had it working fine before, but maybe these files got moved or erased.  I will let you know what I find out, thanks.

Comment: @acj, I did not have the libs/armeabi and libs/armeabi-v7a folders.  I have added them and the the appropriate files under each folder.  However it still has the same failure, is there anything else I need to do to link up these folders?

Comment: The files should appear in a `lib` or `libs` directory once you've unzipped the apk. Be sure to clean the project if you haven't already. From your screenshot, it appears that you're exporting the jar (good). Did you update ADT recently? If possible, please post more of the Logcat output.

Comment: I posted the logcat output.  Still very puzzled by this error, thank you fo helping me out with it.  I don't think I have updated the ADT recently, but possibly I should try rolling back anyways.  Which files do you mean should appear in libs when I;ve unzipped the apk? and which apk? I have copied the jars and dependent files from another project that was using them.  Perhaps that is the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to verify, I loaded up a default project with the library files you are trying to use and verified the same issue.  It's not your IDE configuration; the `gdx-audio` JAR library is not meant to stand alone, it is an extension in the larger `gdx` framework and depends on other classes in other JARs as part of that library package.  Without the classes that `KissFFT` (the class throwing the error) imports, that class cannot be loaded either.

Admittedly the error is a bit misdirecting, it should be telling you that the classes it can't find are `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Disposable` and `com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SharedLibraryLoader`.  It turns out the `com.badlogic.gdx.utils` package is located inside the `gdx.jar` file, so you have to include `gdx.jar` in addition to `gdx-audio.jar` to use that library extension.

As a reference, here's what your libs directory (at a minimum) needs to then look like:
[image]

In case you don't already have it, here is the link to that frameworks official site.  I can't say for sure, but some of the required dependencies would hopefully be somewhere in their documentation: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

**SIDE NOTE:** You should NEVER need to manually add your JAR files to the build path in an Android project using Eclipse.  ADT does the job of taking everything from your `libs/` directory and building it as a dependency.  All you are doing by adding this is creating duplication that eventually will cause you more issues that will be just as hard to track if you ever use a build system besides the one inside Eclipse.

This is why you have to dependency sets in your project list.  "Referenced Libraries" is the one created by Eclipse and should not be there.  "Android Dependencies" is what ADT creates and should be the only library set listed (other than "Android x.x", which is your framework SDK).

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thank you so much for spending the time to look into this for me, I was really at a loss there.  Thank you also for the clarification about Android Dependencies vs Referenced Libraries.   Many thanks